# No Know Class Method in NSString Category

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, objective-c-category

I have a category as defined:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (MyApp)

+ (UIColor *)colorFromHexString;

@end


#import "NSString+MyApp.h"

@implementation NSString (MyApp)

+ (UIColor *)colorFromHexString
{
    self = [self stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];
    unsigned rgbValue = 0;
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
    [scanner scanHexInt:&rgbValue];
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0 green:((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0 blue:(rgbValue & 0xFF)/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}

@end
```

I am getting an error on the line `self = [self stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];` that says: `"No know class method for selector stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString" and "cannot assign self in a class method"`.

I am confused as to why I am not able to do this in an `NSString Category`. I've seen [examples online](http://benscheirman.com/2010/04/handy-categories-on-nsstring/) that do things very similar with 'self' in an `NSString Category` so I am not sure why it isn't working here.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't add categories to system classes.  If you do, you should prefix them with something `_eleven_...` to avoid collisions.  Also, this would probably make more sense as a category on UIColor (as a class method) since it is kinda like a color factory method.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors in your code.

Use the instance method (-) instead of static method (+)

```
// INCORRECT. self in a static method points to class object
// + (UIColor *)colorFromHexString

// CORRECT. self is instance method points to instance of class.
- (UIColor *)colorFromHexString
```

Also on line 1 assign `hexString` instead of `self`.

```
- (UIColor *)colorFromHexString
{
    NSString *hexString = [self stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];
    unsigned rgbValue = 0;
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
    [scanner scanHexInt:&rgbValue];
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0 green:((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0 blue:(rgbValue & 0xFF)/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! FYI. Having hexString as a parameter in scannerWithString: was a typo. I meant to have self in there - not that it worked either way...